# org.webrtc.RTCPeerConnection can not publish video to server

Tags: swift, webrtc

im using webrtc to send and get video in conference. The subcriser video is display normally

But the problem is about the video is not publish to the server, i check the method "setlocalDescription" is not return error, here is my sdp, can anyone help?

I searched a lot soluition but i still can not know my problem, i think it's about codec error, may be the codec is not H264( my server accpept H264) then im trying to force to H264 by using replace profile-level-id to 42e01f, but it's not working.

```
let encoderFactory = RTCVideoEncoderFactoryH264()
let decoderFactory = RTCVideoDecoderFactoryH264()
factory = RTCPeerConnectionFactory(encoderFactory: encoderFactory, decoderFactory: decoderFactory)
```

```
publisherPeerConnection sdp: v=0

o=- 3622980835820981111 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1

s=-

t=0 0

a=group:BUNDLE audio video

a=msid-semantic: WMS ARDAMS

m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126

c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0

a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0

a=ice-ufrag:JkM5

a=ice-pwd:ZA9uRVkCYtN378Y5a3KDdZhH

a=ice-options:trickle renomination

a=fingerprint:sha-256 11:76:45:6E:D7:AF:8F:5C:D6:92:9C:0A:BA:B8:EB:A6:14:9A:5C:2D:2C:67:A2:D9:C6:F1:7D:97:7D:E9:09:0B

a=setup:actpass

a=mid:audio

a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level

a=sendrecv

a=rtcp-mux

a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2

a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc

a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1

a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000

a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000

a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000

a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000

a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000

a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000

a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000

a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000

a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000

a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000

a=ssrc:1949288389 cname:1V8vIuBCo3jUloXY

a=ssrc:1949288389 msid:ARDAMS d7849f66-f8e4-42ef-8e85-58b08cf8c531

a=ssrc:1949288389 mslabel:ARDAMS

a=ssrc:1949288389 label:d7849f66-f8e4-42ef-8e85-58b08cf8c531

m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97

c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0

a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0

a=ice-ufrag:JkM5

a=ice-pwd:ZA9uRVkCYtN378Y5a3KDdZhH

a=ice-options:trickle renomination

a=fingerprint:sha-256 11:76:45:6E:D7:AF:8F:5C:D6:92:9C:0A:BA:B8:EB:A6:14:9A:5C:2D:2C:67:A2:D9:C6:F1:7D:97:7D:E9:09:0B

a=setup:actpass

a=mid:video

a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset

a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time

a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation

a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01

a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay

a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type

a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing

a=sendrecv

a=rtcp-mux

a=rtcp-rsize

a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000

a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir

a=rtcp-fb:96 nack

a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli

a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb

a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc

a=fmtp:96 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f

a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000

a=fmtp:97 apt=96

a=ssrc-group:FID 554880171 3682085542

a=ssrc:554880171 cname:1V8vIuBCo3jUloXY

a=ssrc:554880171 msid:ARDAMS c7384d55-f6f7-45a0-9c83-72b535cf3f30

a=ssrc:554880171 mslabel:ARDAMS

a=ssrc:554880171 label:c7384d55-f6f7-45a0-9c83-72b535cf3f30

a=ssrc:3682085542 cname:1V8vIuBCo3jUloXY

a=ssrc:3682085542 msid:ARDAMS c7384d55-f6f7-45a0-9c83-72b535cf3f30

a=ssrc:3682085542 mslabel:ARDAMS

a=ssrc:3682085542 label:c7384d55-f6f7-45a0-9c83-72b535cf3f30
```

I see the codec for h264 is:

```
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

then the video display is right:

```
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97
```

but what's wrong?
im using iphone 8plus, ios 13.1 to test